# How to slow down animation playback without messing with fps setting so that i can animate in realtime with auto-keyframe on and also sync audio?

Tags: animation, 3d-view

Im looking for is some sort of "time multiplier" slider, end goal is NOT to create bullet time animation but to animate subtle movements with audio in realtime with auto-keyframe on so that the flow the movement can be easily animated with pressing, for example, R key while animation is playing and then i rotate in realtime while animation plays.

If that makes sense.

TLDR, you know then you accidentally leave auto-keyframe on and then grab or rotate anything and now you have wierd animation keyframes, it can be useful if we have control over playback speed and then do it intentionally and not accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Without coding, I think the simplest way is to temporarily set to half (or a quarter) the Frame rate, and set to 0.5 (or 0.25) the "Pitch" property of the sound.

With the pitch sound property trick, you can also scale the timing of your animation, to mantain the frame rate unaltered and so mantain the "time resolution" of the animation.

Comment: I tried that but really its a headache to revert back to the original settings, the keyframes don't sync with audio. I also tried the time remapping feature in the render settings, it does not work with audio sync and keyframes are way off, i can do the coding way if you can tell me, im familiar with console and i know python.

Comment: I'm not expert enough to give you advices on how to code such function, but I tried the procedure with sound pitch to 0.5, animating, then playing back with sound pitch at 1 and animation time scaled by 0.5 on the dopesheet, and it stays perfectly in sync. The only thing to be aware is the fact that you should set the pivot point of the animation scaling at the frame where the sound file starts (or maybe creating a sort of a ciak sync, for manual realign).